# When handling a form submission with addEventListener the action performed is reverted immediately

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

My webpage has a simple form with an input box and the submit button, and an empty paragraph:

```
<form action="" class="form" method="post" id="f">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="txt" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="go">
</form>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

I'm trying to write a script that once the submit button is submitted writes the submitted text into the paragraph:

```
let f = document.getElementById('f')
f.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    let text = document.querySelector('#txt').value
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = text
})
```

And it *kinda* works, meaning that it does shows the text in the paragraph but only for a split second, then it disappears. What am I missing?

Comment: remove that `action` attribute from your form and everything will work like magic ;)

Comment: It isn't reverting. You are submitting your form and the page reloads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `preventDefault`

```
let f = document.getElementById('f');
f.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { // access the submit event
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior of the submit event
  let text = document.querySelector('#txt').value
  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = text
});
```

Comment: I assume you meant **f**.preventDefault?
Anyway, it doesn't work. Console tells me preventDefault is not a function.

Comment: no.. It is `e.preventDefault`. Did you pass e as a parameter to your function?

Comment: Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/0L1mjfge/6/

Comment: You're right I didn't.

So 'e' is just a random character right? Just an object created on the spot which we can attach a function to?

Comment: when you use `addEventListener`, you pass a function to it. This function takes the event object. This object contains all the information about the event. `e` is just a random name given to that even object. You can name it whatever you want. For example if you name it as `event`, then you'd use `event.preventDefault()`. If you name it as `Larn`, then you'd use `Larn.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change input type submit to button. this will not reload page.

```
function callClick(){
let text = document.querySelector('#txt').value
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
<form action="" class="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="txt" value="">
    <input type="button" id="f" name="submitButton" value="go" onclick="callClick()">
</form>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

when I tried to stop people from copying my image i used a Event listener
all you need to do is change contextmenu to p1 and then change #txt to txt